# Use variant from dependency

Tags: ocaml

I have this code:

cnf.mli

```
type literal
type clause
type cnf
type l_diff

val l_compare: literal -> literal -> l_diff
```

cnf.ml (partial)

```
type l_diff = Same | Negation | Different
```

checker.ml (partial)

```
open Cnf
type solution = (literal * bool) list

let rec solve_literal sol l =
    match sol with
    | [] -> false
    | (hl, b)::rs when (l_compare l hl) = Same -> b
    | (hl, b)::rs when (l_compare l hl) = Negation -> not b
    | _::rs -> solve_literal rs l
```

This works in utop using:

```
#mod_use "cnf.ml";;
#use "checker.ml";;
```

But if I try to compile `checker` I get the following error:

compile command:

```
ocamlbuild cnf.cma
ocamlbuild checker.cma
```

error:

```
+ /home/user/.opam/4.05.0/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -o checker.cmo checker.ml
File "checker.ml", line 7, characters 42-46:
Error: Unbound constructor Same
Hint: Did you mean Some?
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 6 targets (2 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

Am I using a variant the wrong way, or using the compiler incorrectly?

Answer (score 5):

Neither, you are using abstract types in signature in the wrong way. When you write in `cnf.mli`

```
type l_diff
```

this declares the type `l_diff` as an abstract type, in other words a black box whose content is hidden.

Contrarily, when using `#mod_use "cnf.ml"` the toplevel infers a signature by itself and makes all type declarations transparent:

```
type literal = …
type clause = …
type cnf = …
type l_diff = Same | Negation | Different

val l_compare: literal -> literal -> l_diff
```

(If you want to see the full inferred signature `ocamlbuild cnf.inferred.mli` should work.)
With this signature, the constructor of `l_diff` are visible and it becomes possible to construct directly or pattern match values of type `l_diff`.

More generally, your signature `cnf.mli` is far too restrictive:
With this signature, the only way to create a value of type `l_diff` is to call `l_compare`. However it would be then impossible to observe the content of the type. Similarly, with the interface `cnf.mli` that you provided, it is impossible to create a value of type `literal`.

Comment: it means that l_diff and other types have to be defined in cnf.mli.

Comment: Perfect thanks, now it work, I don't like very mutch duplication but is ok for now ^^